# reflection - get type of single slice element

Tags: go, reflection, slice

I want to iterate over struct definition recursively and for slices get a type of a singular element. Then, create an empty instance of that type. For example:

```
type Path struct {
  Name string
  Points []Coordinate
}
type Coordinate struct {
  Latitude float64
  Longitude float64
}
```

Assuming that types are unknown at runtime, how can I create an empty instance of the nested type (in the above example Coordinate). I mean:

`x := Coordinate{}`

When at input I get Path (which can be any other struct, with slices of different types)?

Comment: Were you able to get to the `Points` field yourself? All you need is to get the element type of that slice and create a new zero-value of it?

Comment: That is the problem, I don't know how to create te zero-value dynamically using reflection or other method.

Comment: There's a `reflect.Zero` function that takes a `reflect.Type` and returns a `reflect.Value`.

Comment: @mkopriva `reflect.Zero()` returns a non-addressable, non-settable value. It's better to use `reflect.New().Elem()` if it needs to be changed / set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the [`reflect.Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) descriptor of some value, you may use [`reflect.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New) function to obtain a pointer to a new, zeroed value.

This will return you a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) value. This will be a pointer, to get the `reflect.Value` of the pointed object, use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem). To "unwrap" the value held inside `reflect.Value()`, you may use [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface).

So if you have a `reflect.Type` descriptor of a slice, you may use `Type.Elem()` to get the `reflect.Type` descriptor of the element type of the slice.

See this example:

```
p := Path{
    Name: "foo",
    Points: []Coordinate{
        {1.1, 2.2},
        {3.3, 4.4},
    },
}

v := reflect.ValueOf(p)
f := v.FieldByName("Points")

cv := reflect.New(f.Type().Elem()).Elem()
c := cv.Interface()
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", c)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cfdq8B_uFpQ)):

```
main.Coordinate{Latitude:0, Longitude:0}
```